# How can I ensure the last form is not deleted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I've got a simple setup whereby a series of forms have a '+' and '-' button which let you add and remove (i.e. copy or delete) a form. How can I ensure that the last form is never deleted?

```
- + 
<form>
stuff
</form>
```

So for instance, if someone presses the '+' button 3 times, effectively, there will be 4 forms. How can I stop them from deleting the first one, i.e. so that there is always one remaining?

Here's the jQuery for the 'minus' function:

```
$(function() {
$('.removeCreative').click(function() {
    $('#creative').find('form:last').remove();
});
});
```

Is it as simply as something like:

```
if ( $("#creative").length > 0 ) {
//do something
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there...

```
$(function() {

    $('.removeCreative').click(function() {
        if($("#creative").children("form").length > 1){
            $('#creative').find('form:last').remove();
        }
    });

});
```

You can use the `children()` method in JQuery to get all child elements within a given element - to which you can then count with `length` and only allow removal if there are more than one. ensuring you pass a "form" selector as the first `children()` parameter will enable you to get the correct length value if your #creative div has different types of elements than just `form`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(function() {
   $('.removeCreative').click(function() {
     var $forms = $('#creative').find('form');
     if($forms.length > 1){
         $forms.last().remove();
     }
   });
});
```

Comment: It means, your answer was correct, but I can't accept all 3 of your answers! :)

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it.  `$("#creative").length` returns the number of elements found by the selector `#creative`, which is always 1. You want to find the number of forms contained beneath the `#creative` element:

```
if ( $("#creative").find("form").length > 1 ) {
  // Remove the last form...
}
```

Comment: Awesome - duly noted. Thanks, I thought I was close, just couldn't figure it out :S